# PHP Regex for information between h4 tags

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to grab what is the h4 text

```
    $regex = '/<h4>([A-Za-z0-9\,\.])/';
```

I am just getting the first letter back, I cannot figure out how to use * to keep grabbing everything to the first < character.

I have made countless attempts and know I am overlooking something simple.

So I was making that much harder than I needed to, the following works:

```
    $regex = '/<h4>.*?<\/h4>/';
```

Comment: Isn't [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) a good fit?

Comment: @Wrikken Not when you're in PHP. :P I wish it was that easy.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder Did you click Wrikken's link? It's a PHP function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Comment: Apparently not. Apologies to @Wrikken. self -1 for stupidity

Comment: @PhpMyCOder: I was actually wondering who it was going to be this time, you're not the first, won't be the last ;)

Comment: What's worse: I must confess for simple jobs like this I probably would use a regex. It's just not worth pulling out the xml parser just to grab some stuff between to H4's. At least, isn't worth it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can trust that grabbing all characters up to the first `<` is a good enough rule then use this:

```
$regex = '/<h4>([^<]*?)</';
```

Of course that definition will only grab `'The '` from `<h4>The <b>Best</b> Book</h4>` You can fix that be changing it to:

```
$regex = '/<h4>(.*?)<\/h4>/';
```

Which will grab everything between a `<h4>` and a `</h4>`, but still isn't perfect because anything like `<h4 >` or `<h4 style="...">` will break it, along with a million other *valid* HTML examples. If you know that the contents won't have any `<` though, and you know your tag will always be exactly `<h4>` the first one works well enough for your situation.

If your situation is more complex you will want to use something like PHP's DOM extension ([DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)) which is meant for parsing HTML and XML, since neither are regular languages and cannot be parsed error free with regex.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough response.  I greatly appreciate your taking the time out of your day to assist me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function to accomplish this task.

```
**function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches;
}**
```

In the first parameter you have to pass the complete string, and in the second parameter you have to pass the tagname ("h4")..